# Recursion in a stream

Tags: stream, scheme, racket, lazy-sequences

I have the code

```
(define (add-ten s)
(let ([f (lambda(s) ((cons 10 (car (s))) (cdr (s))))])
 (f s)))
```

s could be a stream like powers

```
(define powers (letrec ([f (lambda (x) (cons x (lambda () (f (* x 2)))))]) 
(lambda  ()   (f 2))))
```

My function

```
(result-for-n-times powers 5)
```

gives '(2 4 8 16 32).

Now, i want to define a stream (add-ten) that can take the stream powers and gives another stream.So, if i call it

```
(result-for-n-times (add-ten powers) 5)
```

would give '((10. 2) (10. 4) (10. 8) (10. 16) (10. 32)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define powers
  (letrec ([f (lambda (x)
                (cons x
                      (lambda () (f (* x 2)))))])
    (f 2)))

(define (result-for-n-times s n)
  (if (zero? n)
      '()
      (cons (car s)
            (result-for-n-times ((cdr s)) (sub1 n)))))

(define (add-ten s)
  (letrec ([f (lambda (x)
                (cons (cons 10 (car x))
                      (lambda () (f ((cdr x))))))])
    (f s)))
```

Notice that the `add-ten` procedure receives a stream as a parameter, but also it must return a stream. So `letrec` must be used for defining a procedure that conses each element taken from the original stream, with a promise that keeps on building the stream.

Also notice that you're not actually *calling* the procedure that defines `powers`, you either call it at the end of `powers`' definition or you call it like this: `(powers)` before passing it to `add-ten`. Fixing this, it works as expected:

```
(result-for-n-times (add-ten powers) 5)
=> '((10 . 2) (10 . 4) (10 . 8) (10 . 16) (10 . 32))
```

Comment: That was also one of my attemps so far, but gives me an error application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '((10 . 2) . #<procedure>)
  arguments...: [none]

Comment: @Rea mmm, no. the error is in `powers`. This is a correct version: `(define powers (letrec ([f (lambda (x) (cons x (lambda () (f (* x 2)))))]) (f 2)))`